# Oracle SQL equivalent of MySQL bulk insert

Tags: plsql, yii2, oracle12c, on-duplicate-key, batch-insert

I have a table like this:

```
email (primary-key) | first_contact_date | last_contact_date | due_date | status
```

The user can upload an excel spreadsheet - from a different application - into the table. The excel contains:

```
email | first_contact_date | last_contact_date
```

Once loaded, the user can alter (update) status and due date.

However, about once a week the user will upload the latest excel spreadsheet which contains new AND old records. In other words, some of the rows already exist in the table and have been worked on.

For this reason, we cannot delete the existing records. Instead:

- if the record is new, insert
- if the record already exists in the table (ie email exists) then we need to update the last_contact_date

The excel spreadsheet can contain between 1,000 and 50,000 rows.

What is the most efficient approach to insert the records into Oracle?? Within mySQL I simply used batch insert with "on duplicate update" but Oracle does not have this function.

What is the best approach to take??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Oracle SQL has that ability through the `MERGE` statement.  But are you asking about a raw SQL statement, or does this functionality need to be used through your framework?

Comment: It is used in several places but I just need to see one working syntax and I can take it from there. I am currently migrating from MySQL to Oracle and this is the one piece of code that is not transferring easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) syntax is a bit tricky.  But it's worth using here because it's faster than using some combination of `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements.

```
--Create table and initial data.
create table contacts
(
    email varchar2(100) primary key,
    first_contact_date date,
    last_contact_date date,
    due_date date,
    status varchar2(100)
);

insert into contacts values('a@a.com', sysdate, sysdate, sysdate, 'open');
insert into contacts values('b@b.com', sysdate, sysdate, sysdate, 'open');
commit;


--Merge (upsert) new rows into the table.
merge into contacts
using
(
    select 'b@b.com' email, date '2000-01-01' first_contact_date, date '2000-01-01' last_contact_date from dual union all
    select 'c@c.com' email, date '2000-01-01' first_contact_date, date '2000-01-01' last_contact_date from dual
) new_contacts
on (contacts.email = new_contacts.email)
when matched then update set
    contacts.first_contact_date = new_contacts.first_contact_date,
    contacts.last_contact_date = new_contacts.last_contact_date
when not matched then insert
    values(new_contacts.email, new_contacts.first_contact_date, new_contacts.last_contact_date, null, null);
```

Btw, did you say you're migrating *from* MySQL to Oracle?  I didn't know it was opposite day.

Comment: This is very helpful! Than you. I will test it tomorrow and mark it as answered

Comment: Regarding MySQL: yes I am moving FROM MySQL very reluctantly. Our IT dept says Oracle is better. Personally I cannot see the advantage!! If I had evidence to the contrary I would be happy to wave it about! :-)

Comment: From my limited experience with MySQL, I think Oracle's SQL and PL/SQL syntax is more powerful, which can lead to simpler code and performance boosts.  But the software costs a *mountain* of money.  I'm guessing your IT department isn't paying attention to the price.  Someday, an accountant will have an unpleasant conversation with the CTO, and you'll migrate back.  But hey, at least that gives you some job security.

Answer (score 1):

Yii 2 has [`upsert()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#upsert()-detail) which works in the way you want to, but only supports inserting/updating of one record. So with 50k record, you need 50k upsert queries - definitely not the most efficient solution, but at least syntax is simple and it protects you from race condition (operation is atomic):

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
    ->upsert($tableName, $row, ['last_contact_date' => $row['last_contact_date'])
    ->execute();
```